# Proving a theorem on limits that approach infinity.

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the theorem $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^r}=+\infty$ if r is even. So that means I have to show that for any $N>0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $-x<\delta $ then $\frac{1}{x^r}>N$. First I solved for x in the 'then' statement so I got $x<(\frac{1}{N})^{1/r}$ then multiplied the inequality by -1 so $-x>-(\frac{1}{N})^{1/r}$ then this is the part which I might be wrong; I took the reciprocal of the right hand side of the inequality then I got: $-x<-N^{1/r}$. So if we can now take $\delta =-N^{1/r}$ and hence the theorem is proven?

Comment: Work with positive numbers. Situation is symmetric about $0$, so we only care about $|x|$ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What one must show is that, for every positive $N$, there exists a positive $\delta$ such that:
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad-\delta\leqslant x\lt 0\implies 1/x^r\geqslant N.
$$
So, fix $N\gt0$. Which $\delta\gt0$ would do the job?

Answer (score 1):

You’re getting your signs a bit confused. The way you’ve set things up, your $x$ is negative, so it’s bound to be less than $\left(\frac1N\right)^{1/r}$; what’s important is that $-x<\left(\frac1N\right)^{1/r}$. Now you can multiply through by $-1$ to get $x>-\left(\frac1N\right)^{1/r}$, an inequality involving two negative numbers. When you take reciprocals, you must do it on **both** sides of the inequality. Since the two numbers have the same sign, you must also reverse the inequality: $$\frac1x<-N^{1/r}\;,$$ which isn’t very useful. But this last step was unnecessary. Go back and simply set $\delta=\left(\frac1N\right)^{1/r}$: then whenever $0<-x<\delta$ you have $$\frac1{-x}>\frac1\delta=N^{1/r}$$ and therefore $\dfrac1{(-x)^r}>N$. Finally, $r$ is even, so $(-x)^r=x^r$.

Comment: Yeah, I was too focused on getting a value for delta. I'm not very comfortable with assuming a value; but it works anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting much into your general strategy to prove the said statement - if $ -(\frac{x}{1})=-x>-(\frac{1}{N})^{\frac{1}{r}}=-(\frac{1}{N^{\frac{1}{r}}})$, than $ -\frac{1}{x} < -(N)^{\frac{1}{r} } $.